# how does asp.net tag works on html page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have put following code on html page.

```
<td bgcolor="<%=TableHeaderColor%>">&nbsp;</td>
```

However it seems html understand above code and it renders colors. when I change letters in between 
`<%= %>` , I get different colors.

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: It allows you to write inline response from server

Comment: The ASP tags are interpreted by the webserver and translated to HTML before sending it to the user.

Comment: ok, then how do I get different colors when I edit them on destop without a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Html doesn't understand a thing, webserver does. Before the page is sent to the client, it's being translated every time and the client (web browser) sees only the generated html result.

Comment: To prove this, have a look at the source once it's in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

In page load : (Server side)

```
page-load ()

{
if(any condition )
{
TableHeaderColor="Red";
}
else if(any condition )
{
TableHeaderColor="Yellow";
}
else if(any condition )
{
TableHeaderColor="Green";
}


}
```

Now if you call this *TableHeaderColor* in your client side as your way , it's changing on your condition ,

**It's just a key only**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<td style="background:<%=TableHeaderColor%>">&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the asp.net tags you write will be translated once they pass the server.
For example: when you use the tag `<asp:hyperlink>` it will be translated to `<a href="">`
try opening the source of a website written in asp, you won't see the asp tags but just html

Answer (score 0):

Is not intepreted by HTML, but by server side page processing.

Ref:

> With ASP, code was enclosed within <%... %> tags and page processing
>   began with the first statement following the first <%> tag. With
>   ASP.NET, any code that is to be processed as soon as the page is
>   loaded must be included within the Page_Load intrinsic event. You can
>   still write code in <%... %> blocks, but it will be executed at render
>   time (in top-down fashion, as in ASP) after the page is loaded. If you
>   need to execute initialization code, it should appear in the Page_Load
>   event, which is raised immediately after the page is loaded by the
>   ASP.NET engine

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f0111sbh(v=vs.100).aspx